# keep "session only" cookies, iOS

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, session-cookies

I'm creating an app that connects to a website, and I don't want the user to need to enter their user credentials every time the app loads. The website returns a session cookie (no expiry date set). Is there any problem with me holding on to that cookie indefinitely? If I just reload it when the app starts, it seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each application has its own cookie store. So if there is no expiration on the cookie, and you don't delete it, and the app isn't deleted, then there's no problem with using it for as long as you like.

---

**EDIT** Here are some links for more opinions and insight:

- [Persisting Cookies In An iOS Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597763/persisting-cookies-in-an-ios-application)"
- [iPhone: NSHTTPCookie is not saved across app restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662530/iphone-nshttpcookie-is-not-saved-across-app-restarts)

My opinion on the matter is that the mobile environment is fundamentally different from the desktop environment. "Quitting" a mobile application is in no way similar to quitting a desktop application. Quitting a mobile application is similar to switching focus on a desktop. You would not expect to re-authenticate every time you pressed Cmd-Tab.

Limiting the life of session tokens is a valuable security precaution, but is correctly implemented on the server side, not the client side. If the server is designed to allow a session to persist indefinitely (because the desktop app is never quit), then there is no reason to not continue the session on a mobile platform in a similar way.

Note that there are other solutions, such as storing the user credentials in keychain so that you can reuse them. This is appropriate in many cases, but it actually is a lower-security solution than persisting the session token indefinitely. If you're going to hold onto an authentication credential forever, it's better that it be a single-purpose token (i.e. a session cookie) rather than a multi-use username and password.

Comment: Is this considered really bad practice, since the cookie is really only supposed to be used for the single session and should expire right after?

Comment: Thanks. Great answer! I appreciate the detail.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no problem** in you allowing this cookie to be set, each application has a cookie store from which you can if you need to check the cookies, however I assume that since this is only a session cookie, you will only need to allow it's existence and let the user leverage the web service until such time the user logs out.

I have done this with some of my apps also.

Good luck.