# Swift Store cookie in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, uiwebview

I'm trying to create a simple webview app of my website, I load the url, make some actions (saving cookies) without problems but, when I close and re-open my app, all cookies are destroyed.
Where is the problem?
Thanks.

```
super.viewDidLoad()

let urlString = "http://my.url"

let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Can you add the bit of code that actually sets or retrieves the cookie?

Comment: I save the cookie in website not in the app.I've created a php script in my site that save a cookie when you visit the page, I open the website in the webview and the script save the cookie and see me it ($_COOKIE["ok"]) but when I close the app, I lose the cookie.

Comment: In any case, looking at the code would help. Are you setting a proper expiration date while creating the cookie?

Comment: No, but the code is only this.. the problem is with every website

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662530/iphone-nshttpcookie-is-not-saved-across-app-restarts

Comment: I'm using swift but.. I've already converted and used it and.. not work